# Unknown temp file in C:/Temp/ generated by a .Net app which sends files to a remote web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, file, arrays

We are running a file sending app on a client server. The app convert files to `ByteArray` and send it to a web service.

At the beginning, we don't have the right to change C:/ Drive. The app comes an error message: "Could not find a part of the path C:/temp/[hash code name].tmp"

Then we asked the administrator to give us a full control of it, and I manually created the temp folder, then it works.

The next day, when we restart the app, it no long sends file, instead it gives us this message.
"Could not find a part of the path C:/temp/**1**/[hash code name].tmp".

I've no idea what is the temp file, is it the ByteArray? will it automatically be written to a temp file in C:/? Can I specify the location of the temp file. Why sometime the temp file is in the sub folder of the temp folder (e.g. folder 1)? Why the app cannot automatic create folder 1 with in the temp folder by itself?

Comment: What are the environment variables TEMP and TMP set to?

Comment: @dsolimano the environment variables keeps default. I've no idea why it generate temp files. Can you show me how to specify environment variables within the application?